# React facebook permisions if user is in a specific facebook group

Tags: reactjs, facebook, permissions

Would like to register a user to db using his facebook details, but he is only allowed to register if he is in a specific facebook group any suggestions
Able to get users basic details (name ,surname, email etc.) ,suspect I am suppose to do something with the permission but read the docs but still getting stuck

```
<FacebookLogin
          appId="304489330816284"
          autoLoad={false}
          fields="name,email,picture"
          onClick={this.componentClicked}
          callback={this.responseFacebook}
          scope="public_profile,user_friends"
          render={renderProps => (
            <button onClick={renderProps.onClick}>Register with Facebook</button>
          )}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `user_groups` permission with the `/me/groups` endpoint to read the groups of a user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

Comment: Hi , so have read th docs but still a bit confused on the user_groups do you have a link or maybe an example you could send ,would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean? user_groups is just a permission you need to authorize